# I am getting "module not found : no module named 'tableau server client'" in my python script

Tags: python, shell, tableau-api, pyenv-virtualenv

I am creating virtual environment & using that in my script.

my library site packages located at:

"/c/sparrow/acnt/rh-python38/root/local/lib/python3.8/site-pack/

my virtual env script:
Location with name: /c/sparrow/acnt/vir_env.sh

```
python_path=/c/sparrow/acnt/rh-python38/root/usr/bin/python
${python_path} -m venv /c/sparrow/emp/.rmp_rp
source /c/sparrow/emp/.rmp_rp
python_path= /c/sparrow/emp/.rmp_rp
```

here the path I have checked "/c/sparrow/acnt/rh-python38/root/usr/bin/"
a) python is symbolic link points to ./python3
b) python3 is a symbolic link points to python3.8

my shell script:
location with name: /c/sparrow/acnt/trigger.sh

```
/c/sparrow/acnt/vir_env.sh

python_path=/c/sparrow/acnt/rh-python38/root/usr/bin/python
source /c/sparrow/emp/.rmp_rp/bin/activate
python_path= /c/sparrow/emp/.rmp_rp/bin/python

${python_path}/c/sparrow/acnt/test.py
```

my python script:
location with name: /c/sparrow/acnt/test.py

```
import tableauserverclient

print("hello")
```

I explained above what I tried.
But I am getting module not found error even after libraries are there.

I think error might be in virtual environment.

Please help on this

Comment: Uhh, `${python_path}/c/sparrow/acnt/test.py` are you sure you want to execute your script that way? Should there not be a space after the `${python_path}`? In fact forget that could you have not written `python /c/sparrow/acnt/test.py` given you seem to have activated the virtual environment? What is the content of the shebang line inside your `test.py` file?

Comment: the space and all come.I didnt give any shebang line in test.py...${python_path} triggers the python only

Comment: I'm with Abdul here: You should **EITHER** use `activate` and `python` **OR** the absolute `python_path` to the venv's binary, but never both. Once you have this sorted out, see if your package is actually installed with `python -m pip list`.

Answer (score 1):

Module Not found error basically most of the time means one of the two:

1. You don't have that module

   pip3 install tableauserverclient
2. Make sure you have this module installed within your virtual env (If you are using one)

Comment: How can check in virtual env wheter the pacakges are added or not

Comment: `pip3 list` should show all packages installed. There's also no harm in trying to install it again. If its installed, pip says that its already installed